# Rails 3 Server Startup problem with fastercsv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails 2.3.5 app getting upgraded to Rails 3. I did every thing I am required to do for upgrading and when I start the rails server using

```
rails server
```

it gives me this

```
Please switch to Ruby 1.9's standard CSV library.  It's FasterCSV plus
support for Ruby 1.9's m17n encoding engine.
```

I am using `ruby-1.9.2-p0` and have `fastercsv (1.5.3) gem` installed. with the help of puts statements, i was able to track down where the error occurred. i found that the execution stops at this line

```
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)
```

in application.rb file. I tried many things but none worked .. please help..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove fasterCSV from your Gemfile in the application. Bundler is trying to require FasterCSV because you have it specified in the Gemfile.

Comment: I got this error application.rb:54:in `require': no such file to load -- fastercsv (LoadError)

Comment: actually i have a set of require statements in the application.rb for gems that are used in the app one of which is require 'fastercsv' in 54th line.

Comment: You should not be putting requires for gems in your application.rb like that. Use bundler to configure all the required gems for your project as this is the new defacto method of including gems in a project.

Comment: Also it looks like fastercsv is the standard now with ruby 1.9 and you may not even need to require fastercsv or even include it as a gem.

Comment: inside of bundler? Yes. The Bundler.require function is actually designed to iterate through the list of gems in the Gemfile and require them into your project.

Answer (score 7):

with 1.9 you no longer need/can use the fastercsv gem, since it's bundled in the std lib.
Now you just need to do:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.open("temp.csv", "w") do |csv|
  csv << ["line1row1", "line1row2"]
  csv << ["line2row1", "line2row2"]
  # ...
end
```

Comment: const_missing': Please switch to Ruby 1.9's standard CSV library.  It's FasterCSV plus support for Ruby 1.9's m17n encoding engine. (NotImplementedError)

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution i found:

```
require 'fastercsv'
require 'csv'

class ImportFileToAssetsWithFasterCsv < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    if CSV.const_defined? :Reader
    csv = FasterCSV
    else
    csv = CSV
    end

    file = 'db/staticfiles/DB-good-rightnames-forimport.csv'
    csv.foreach(file) do |row|
      Asset.create!(:country => row[0], :city => row[1], :latlong => row[2], :XX => row[3], :DEC => row[4], :point_name => row[5], :system_type => row[6], :system_brand => row[7], :function => row[8], :operator_name => row[9], :operator_brand => row[10], :parent_company => row[11], :app => "WWW", :language => "en", :source => "XXX", :Z_name => "International", :pref_format => "")
    end
  end

  def self.down
    IspcAsset.destroy_all()
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Look here too http://www.wherethebitsroam.com/blogs/jeffw/fastercsv-csv-ruby-18-19-and-rails-30

Answer (score 1):

If used FasterCsv in loop or in the code just change it with Csv and works for me.
Remove gem 'fastercsv' from gem file.
Just write your code in controller, no need add other code in somewhere in config.

This is the example of wrong code.

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
    require 'fastercsv'


def download_csv
    @invitation = Invitation.find(params[:id])
    @activities = Version.where("created_at >= ?", @invitation.created_at)
    if params[:export]

      csv_string = FasterCSV.generate do |csv|
      # header row
            csv << ["Date", "Event", "Details"]

            @activities.each do |act|
              csv << [act.created_at.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"), act.event, act.item_id]

            end
      end   
        timestamp = Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')
        send_data csv_string,
            :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present',
            :disposition => "attachment; filename=goal_history_#{timestamp}.csv"
    end
  end
```

and just corrected with changing word FasterCsv to Csv and it works. like below

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
    require 'csv'


def download_csv
    @invitation = Invitation.find(params[:id])
    @activities = Version.where("created_at >= ?", @invitation.created_at)
    if params[:export]

      csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
      # header row
            csv << ["Date", "Event", "Details"]

            @activities.each do |act|
              csv << [act.created_at.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"), act.event, act.item_id]

            end
      end   
        timestamp = Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')
        send_data csv_string,
            :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present',
            :disposition => "attachment; filename=goal_history_#{timestamp}.csv"
    end
  end
```